# Can't launch Wakanda server. Force prompt an admin access

Tags: wakanda

I have a solution where I had a user1. I have add this user in the `Admin` group to give him access to the server. Then I change the name in `admin` and set the password to `admin1234`. Then ehn I start the server and it ask for the pass, I enter the new one but it doesn't work. So I remove my user and create a new one, still the same... I remove all the user and have only the default `Admin` group with no user, but still impossible to run anything. I always get ask for the admin pass when I have no user in the directory.

I have try to do a custom required.js function, I have try with the basic settings... I tried everything but I can't make my project to run.

Anybody have an idea of what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I think the directory use the usernam to hash the password. When I have changed the username to `admin`, it broke the hashing phase, since then I'm not able to do anything :(. Now I have to recreate a project from scratch and copy all the file....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the admin user, kill the server process and then create a new admin user.
I had the same issue a long time ago and this worked for me.

Comment: The server was nerver stop correctly, so to force kill and restart make it. Thanks.